# Write and read non-serializable object to file android example

Tags: java, android, makefile, stream, serialization

I couldn't find a good example, so after some fighting with writing non-serializable object to file in Android, I decided to show you my solution. Could you tell me if it is OK or how could it be improved?

This class is used to store information in a file. `writeObject` and `readObject` methods were created, because `android.graphics.Point` is not serializable. This is the reason why `strokes` was declared as transient. To make sure that we are able to overwrite file, we need to create our own `ObjectOutputStream`, which overrides `writeStreamHeader`, so the second header will not be appended to our file. We check if the file size is greater that zero, and according to this we create our `OutputStream`.

In general, what I understand is that to write a non-serializable object to file we need to make it transient and define our `readObject`and `writeObject` methods. To overwrite a file we need to make our own `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Environment;

public class LogInfo implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 710487907869630527L;

    transient public ArrayList<Point[][]> strokes;

    public LogInfo()
    {
        strokes = new ArrayList<Point[][]>();
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException 
    {
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
        stream.writeInt(strokes.size());
        Point[][] pointsArray = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < strokes.size(); i++)
        {
            pointsArray = ((Point[][])strokes.get(i));
            stream.writeInt(pointsArray.length);
            for (int j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
            {
                stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j].length);
                for (int k = 0; k < pointsArray[j].length; k++)
                {
                    stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].x);
                    stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ClassCastException
    {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        strokes = new ArrayList<Point[][]>();
        int strokesSize = stream.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < strokesSize; i++)
        {
            int arrayXSize = stream.readInt();
            Point[][] points = new Point[arrayXSize][];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayXSize; j++)
            {
                int arrayYSize = stream.readInt();
                points[j] = new Point[arrayYSize];
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayYSize; k++)
                    points[j][k] = new Point(stream.readInt(), stream.readInt());
            }
            strokes.add(points);
        }
    }

    public void writeLog()
    {
        File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "data.log");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            ObjectOutputStream writer;
            if(file.length() > 0)
            {
                writer = new MyObjectOutputStream(fos);
            }
            else
            {
                writer = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            }
            writer.writeObject(this);
            writer.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<LogInfo> readLog()
    {
        ArrayList<LogInfo> logInfoArray = new ArrayList<LogInfo>();
        try{
            File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "data.log");
            FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            while (file.canRead())
            {
                logInfoArray.add((LogInfo) reader.readObject());
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         //TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return logInfoArray;
    }
}

class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        super(os);
      }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small detail: you don't need to make `strokes` transient.  When you override `readObject`/`writeObject`, you completely override the usual serialization mechanism.

Transient just means that the usual serialization mechanism should skip that member when marshalling/unmarshalling the whole object.

Otherwise, it looks pretty good.  I haven't checked explicitly that `readObject`/`writeObject` process everything in the same order, but hopefully you made some unit test that checks for that.

Comment: If strokes are not transient, it tries to serialize them by default and it does not work. It only works when they are transient...